# SVG corrupted in XCode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, svg, figma

There is a problem with exported SVG from figma. In all svg previews (chrome, macos preview, online svg editors) it's works the same. But when import svg to xcode in looks bad.

SVG contains gaussian blur, and xcode is not recognizing it, at all. Insted of circle blur, it shows circles.

```xml
<svg width="375" height="812" viewBox="0 0 375 812" fill="none"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g clip-path="url(#clip0_1034_16214)">
        <rect width="375" height="812" fill="#000028"/>
        <g opacity="0.5" filter="url(#filter0_f_1034_16214)">
            <circle cx="43.5" cy="35.5" r="127.5" fill="#678AF8"/>
        </g>
        <g opacity="0.5" filter="url(#filter1_f_1034_16214)">
            <circle cx="247.5" cy="752.5" r="127.5" fill="#10C3EA"/>
        </g>
        <g filter="url(#filter2_f_1034_16214)">
            <circle cx="162.5" cy="0.5" r="68.5" fill="white"/>
        </g>
        <g filter="url(#filter3_f_1034_16214)">
            <circle cx="306.5" cy="571.5" r="68.5" fill="white"/>
        </g>
    </g>
    <defs>
        <filter id="filter0_f_1034_16214" x="-350" y="-358" width="787" height="787" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
            <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
            <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="133"/>
        </filter>
        <filter id="filter1_f_1034_16214" x="-146" y="359" width="787" height="787" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
            <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
            <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="133"/>
        </filter>
        <filter id="filter2_f_1034_16214" x="-172" y="-334" width="669" height="669" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
            <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
            <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="133"/>
        </filter>
        <filter id="filter3_f_1034_16214" x="-28" y="237" width="669" height="669" filterUnits="userSpaceOnUse" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
            <feFlood flood-opacity="0" result="BackgroundImageFix"/>
            <feBlend mode="normal" in="SourceGraphic" in2="BackgroundImageFix" result="shape"/>
            <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="133"/>
        </filter>
        <clipPath id="clip0_1034_16214">
            <rect width="375" height="812" fill="white"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

Expected result:
[image]

Actual result:
[image]

I didn't find any topic that would have the same or similar problem.

FYI:
I can't create blur from code, because I need to add this image in `LaunchScreen.storyboard`.

Is there some workaround to do fix it? Or any other possible solutions?

Update: That's problem in XCode himself. I think XCode import of SVG not works with filters at all. And workaround for it to use png or pdf. But it would cost a lot of space in resources.

Comment: Please check if the id-s are unique. Also you can remove the clipPath since it clips a rect as big as the viewBox.

Comment: @enxaneta they are unique, and any other editor is showing as expected.

Comment: UIKit does not support every SVG command. Is your goal is the first image? Just very, very faint color differences? If so, any reason not to pre-render that as a .png for your launch screen?

Comment: Move the defs before the elements so they don't have a forward reference. This shouldn't be necessary but maybe there's an iOS bug here.